# Google Maps Javascript API no me funciona

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

tengo un problema con la API ya que no me muestra el mapa y la consola del navegador no me muestra errores, les dejo el código ya que de verdad no encuentro el error, mi aplicación es en Angular y no esta en producción en este momento.

les adjunto el código y la consola del navegador. Muchas gracias!

```
<script>
   function initMap() {
    console.log("hola");
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
   });
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: uluru,
     map: map
   });
 } 
</script>



<div id="map"></div>
  <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->    

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=--aqui 
inserte mi key --&callback=initMap"></script>
```

[image: noErrorConsoleLog]

dejo mi html completo -------

```
             <div class="card mb-3">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="../../../assets/images/ciudades/moscu.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"> ---NOMBRE CIUDAD --- </h5>
                <p class="card-text">  

                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ut ligula a ipsum bibendum pharetra a nec leo. Vestibulum tempus ipsum orci, et finibus tellus hendrerit eget. Nam at consequat velit, id iaculis risus. Curabitur mollis dolor sit amet molestie faucibus. Pellentesque ut malesuada felis. Maecenas velit nisi, euismod non ullamcorper ut, porttitor vel sem. Vestibulum ac dolor nec lacus mattis tincidunt non ac ante. Etiam nec faucibus tortor. In commodo pellentesque turpis, nec iaculis elit blandit pellentesque. Donec sit amet suscipit velit. Etiam urna magna, tempus sit amet rutrum sed, rhoncus quis orci. Nulla ut leo turpis. Donec laoreet lectus sed pretium luctus. In eleifend quis odio in fermentum. Aliquam facilisis erat nec sagittis hendrerit. Pellentesque condimentum, diam vitae rutrum pretium, neque enim lobortis tellus, nec mattis nisi tellus a magna.
                  Donec vel ornare orci, et varius nulla. Ut efficitur vitae dolor ac consequat. Sed nec tincidunt purus. Praesent at venenatis dui. Phasellus facilisis at felis vitae gravida. Aenean luctus, felis eget euismod sollicitudin, ipsum magna ultricies elit, eget sagittis tellus odio sit amet arcu. Maecenas at augue urna. Donec sed convallis enim. Mauris dui dolor, aliquam ac rhoncus in, sollicitudin quis turpis. Vestibulum faucibus sit amet ex eget auctor. Nunc commodo eget massa et finibus. Mauris ornare quis quam id finibus. Duis lobortis suscipit tellus, eget ornare tellus tristique non. Curabitur eu cursus augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin faucibus ipsum ac posuere consectetur.   

                </p>

              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="card mb-3">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Lugares Históricos</h5>
                <p class="card-text">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ut ligula a ipsum bibendum pharetra a nec leo. Vestibulum tempus ipsum orci, et finibus tellus hendrerit eget. Nam at consequat velit, id iaculis risus. Curabitur mollis dolor sit amet molestie faucibus. Pellentesque ut malesuada felis. Maecenas velit nisi, euismod non ullamcorper ut, porttitor vel sem. Vestibulum ac dolor nec lacus mattis tincidunt non ac ante. Etiam nec faucibus tortor. In commodo pellentesque turpis, nec iaculis elit blandit pellentesque. Donec sit amet suscipit velit. Etiam urna magna, tempus sit amet rutrum sed, rhoncus quis orci. Nulla ut leo turpis. Donec laoreet lectus sed pretium luctus. In eleifend quis odio in fermentum. Aliquam facilisis erat nec sagittis hendrerit. Pellentesque condimentum, diam vitae rutrum pretium, neque enim lobortis tellus, nec mattis nisi tellus a magna. Donec vel ornare orci, et varius nulla. Ut efficitur vitae dolor ac consequat. Sed nec tincidunt purus. Praesent at venenatis dui. Phasellus facilisis at felis vitae gravida. Aenean luctus, felis eget euismod sollicitudin, ipsum magna ultricies elit, eget sagittis tellus odio sit amet arcu. Maecenas at augue urna. Donec sed convallis enim. Mauris dui dolor, aliquam ac rhoncus in, sollicitudin quis turpis. Vestibulum faucibus sit amet ex eget auctor. Nunc commodo eget massa et finibus. Mauris ornare quis quam id finibus. Duis lobortis suscipit tellus, eget ornare tellus tristique non. Curabitur eu cursus augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin faucibus ipsum ac posuere consectetur.



                </p>
              </div>

            </div>



            <script>
                function initMap() {
                  console.log("hola");
                  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
                  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: uluru
                  });
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: uluru,
                    map: map
                  });
                }
            </script>


            <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
                <div id="map" ></div>
                <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->




                <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= <aqui inserte mi api key> &callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: 1.- Dale un alto al div que contendrá el mapa. (Por experiencia te digo esto)
2.- Añade tu api key que se genera en la consola de google developers

Comment: ¿Un alto al div?

Comment: si `<div id="map" style="height:400px"></div>`

Comment: aaaaah yaya, si lo tengo


    #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }

Comment: Que sucedió? nada aun?

Comment: nop nada jajaja llevo 2 dias en esto

Comment: Añádelo directamente en el html, revisa que se este aplicando el estilo, a menos que tengas otras cosas, a mí con tu código si aparece el mapa

Comment: Si creo otro archivo html y utilizo este mismo código, corre perfectamente, pero en mi aplicación no quiere funcionar.

Comment: De hecho ni se muestra el console log que escribí.

Comment: Muestra todo el contenido de tu archivo, puede ser que no estes colocando correctamente algo o que interfiera  para poder emular tu situación

Comment: listo mostre todo el contenido de mi código

Comment: Intenta poner el estilo directamente el en div `<div id="map" style="clear:both; height:400px;"></div> `